# RESTHeart Distinct Query Filter for MongoDB

Tags: restheart

### Hi ,

Can anyone help me how to get Unique column data using RESTHeart filter query's from MongoDB.
 ##

**

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an [aggregation](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/AwDw) using the $group operator